# VueJS, Vuex and complex state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've managed to break VueJS reactivity with my Vuex store thanks (I think) to a complex data model.  The data is an object of arrays of objects as follows:

```
"users": { 
  "2017": [
    { id: 1, name: "bob" },
    { id: 2, name: "jane" },
  ],
  "2016": [ 
    ...
  ]
},
"dude": null
```

I had originally been storing ES6 classes in the store (I have a lot of helper functions) but have since removed that.

In order to access the right user I have a computed property as follows:

```
  computed: {
    user () {
      return this.$store.state.users.users[this.$store.state.users.currentDate][this.$store.state.users.currentUserIndex]
    },
    ...
```

The problem occurs when I commit a mutation to update the name (for example), I can see in the Chrome Vue debugger that the state has changed however the template has not (i.e. `user.name` continues to be the previous name).

Here is the code for the mutation:

```
  PATCH_USER (state, payload) {
    let index = state.users[state.currentDate].findIndex((el) => el.id === payload.user.id)
    let user = Object.assign(state.users[state.currentDate][index], payload.user)
    Vue.set(state.users[state.currentDate], index, user)
  },
```

Now, that part that makes me thing I'm doing something silly.  If I add a computed property for `dude` (root level state item) and then include it in the template then the user name is correctly updated.

There is a lot more to the application but hopefully I'm doing something wrong with what I've shown.

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Figures after 8 hours of wrestling with this the answer seems to have come within 2 mins of posting to SO. (thanks @blockhead and @bert-evans).

I *thought* I had checked all of the code for this however it turns out the very first time data was loaded from the backend server it was wrong. `payload` is the response from the web API:

```
// bad 
SET_USERS (state, payload) {
  state.users[state.currentDate] = payload.users
}

// good
SET_USERS (state, payload) {
  Vue.set(state.users, state.currentDate, payload.users)
}
```

Comment: If you see the update in the vue dev tools right away, without having to refresh, that means it's already reactive.

Comment: How do you updated the user? Can we see the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was indeed incorrectly assigning a new key to an existing Vuex object.  The following code using `Vue.set` resolved the issue:

```
SET_USERS (state, payload) {
  // object, key, value
  Vue.set(state.users, state.currentDate, payload.users)
}
```